# how to display html data in UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I want to display json data(Jsp server) in my UITableviewcell. The following below is my json data

```
[{"result":[{"notification_id":106,"title":"Service Request","message":"your reqeust Â PAD_0000882 is In-Process","notification_created_time":"Nov18,13"},{"notification_id":158,"title":"Service Request","message":"your reqeust Â PAD_0000896 is In-Process","notification_created_time":"Nov19,13"}
```

I had took three UILables in UITaleviewcell and display the data like  title and message and time. I have small doubt how to display message data(your reqeust Â PAD_0000896 is In-Process) in UILabel. the message data is like html tag.i had no idea how to display the html data in UILabel.i am having idea how to display title and time in uilabel.

This is my code.

jsondata.m

```
NSArray *arrResults = [dict1 valueForKey:@"result"];

listOfObjects = [NSMutableArray array];


for (NSDictionary *dictRes in arrResults)

{


for (NSDictionary *dictResSub in dictRes)

{

Attributes *at = [[Attributes alloc] init];


at.message = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"message"];


[listOfObjects addObject:at];

}

}

[tableVwTotalRequests reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *identifier=@"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) 

{

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

}


UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.325490196 green:0.3960784 blue:0.90196078 alpha:1];

cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;




UILabel *lblDesc=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 100, 20)];

lblDesc.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

lblDesc.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lblDesc];


Attributes *att = [listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


strRequestId=att.requestId;



lblDesc.text=att.message;




return cell;

}
```

Comment: are you looking for HTML conversion to plain text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to convert the json to NSDictionary. And then you can query NSDictionary to get the required string and then use `NSString stringWithFormat:` to format the string and set the formatted string to the UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary has a key of 'result' that has an array of 'notification' dictionaries, where each dictionary has the keys 'title', 'message' and 'notification_created_time'.

your table view is a list of these 'notification' objects so when you convert the JSON to Foundation objects using NSJSONSerialization you build an array of 'notification' objects;

for each cell, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you retrieve the 'notification' dictionary from this array using the indexPath.row and then get at the values from this dictionary to populate your labels.